# Проблема с перегрузкой списка list.add

Tags: c#, ооп

Я новичок в C# и у меня проблема с перегрузкой списка list,при попытке заполнить список данными из файла появляется ошибка перегрузки списка `List<Books>`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Курсовая_негра;

namespace Курсовая_негра
{
    internal class Books
    {
        string s;
        string author;
        int zalog_cost;
        int cost_prokat;
        string jenre;
        public string S { get { return s; } }
        public string Author { get { return author; } }
        public int Zalog_cost { get { return zalog_cost; } }
        public int CostProkat { get { return cost_prokat; } }
        public string Jenre { get { return jenre; } }
        public Books(string S, string Author, int Zalog_cost, int CostProkat, string Jenre)
        {
            s = S;
            author = Author;
            zalog_cost = Zalog_cost;
            cost_prokat = CostProkat;
            jenre = Jenre;
        }
        public void printBooks()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Название: {0};\nАвтор: {1};\nСтоимость книги: {2}$;\nСтоимость проката книги: {3}$;\nЖанр: {4};", s, author, zalog_cost, cost_prokat, jenre);
        }
    }
}
class BooksFile
{
    List<Books> m;
    int l;
    public int L { get { return l; } }
    public BooksFile()
    {
        m = new List<Books>();
        string S = "";
        string Author = "";
        int Zalog_cost = 0;
        int CostProkat = 0;
        string Jenre = "";
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Artem\\source\\repos\\негры\\негры\\Books.txt");
            while (true)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;
                if (Int32.TryParse(line, out CostProkat))
                { 
                    S = sr.ReadLine();
                    Author = sr.ReadLine();
                    Zalog_cost = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                    CostProkat = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                    Jenre = sr.ReadLine();
                    m.AddRange(S,Author,Zalog_cost,CostProkat,Jenre);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine($"Некорректный ввод  ");
            }
            sr.Close();
           
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Нет файла! ");
        }
        l=m.Count;
    }
    public void BooksUses()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Книги: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            m[i].printBooks();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
Ошибка CS1501 Ни одна из перегрузок метода "AddRange" не принимает 5 аргументов.
```

Comment: Какая ошибка то? Полный текст ошибки должен быть в вопросе

Comment: Ошибка CS1501 Ни одна из перегрузок метода "AddRange" не принимает 5 аргументов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m.AddRange(S,Author,Zalog_cost,CostProkat,Jenre);

Ошибка CS1501 Ни одна из перегрузок метода "AddRange" не принимает 5 аргументов.
```

Посмотрим описание метода `AddRange`:

> Добавляет элементы указанной коллекции в конец списка List.

Это совсем не то, что вам нужно. Вы ведь явно хотите добавить в список новый объект класса `Books`, а для этого нужно его создать и добавить через метод `Add`:

```
m.Add(new Books(S,Author,Zalog_cost,CostProkat,Jenre));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ

Answer (score 0):

К примеру чтобы добавить 'значения' Через:

```
List<Books> m = new List<Books>();
m.AddRange()//Добавляет только 'Массив Объектов' тоесть, массивы: string[],object[],int[] и тд.
m.AddRange(new object[]{S,Author,Zalog_cost,CostProkat,Jenre}); //Можно так. В вашем случае вы добавляете данные которые не являются массивом.
m.Add(S,Author,Zalog_cost,CostProkat,Jenre); // Как и описал выше CrazyElf
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ